# MongoDB geospatial search to return area with most results in a given radius

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/

- A collection where each doc has a GeoJSON object.
- Each doc can be found by 1 or more users.

What we would like to be able to do is run a query to fetch the a batch of docs related to 1 user where the docs are the 20 within closest proximity to each other.

For example:

- 100 docs for user Bob
- bob loads a page and the API returns 20 docs
- these 20 docs when all placed on a map represent the most densly clustered locations in the collection.
- - in other words.. they could all be in the city, say London.

Is this even possible and/ or sensible?

Comment: GeoSpatial queries in Mongo are CPU intensive as they have a lot of math involved.  Trying to find all records for a radius of a specific point is one thing, but trying to find and compare the records between any two points, where the number of points is near infinite will likely not work.  If you were able to generalize the problem statement there are other options.  Let's say, you have 5 cities you wish to compare, then the query will result in 5 distinct GeoSpatial calculations and record identifications.  This is expected to be roughly 5 times the work of a single GeoSpatial calculation.

Comment: If you can instead, add a city field to your document and use a standard index on the field `city` you will avoid the math calculations and the CPU intensive search required by a GeoSpatial index.

Comment: Of course, not all cities have the same radius.  So density calculations would be difficult unless you also included the area of the city too.

Comment: Check out Uber H3 - https://eng.uber.com/visualizing-city-cores-with-h3/

Comment: Hmm ok thanks for the info. So without re-engineering the better approach is design the UI to get the starting point decision from the human